# Erro ao desestruturar valor em função: TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, objetos

Gostaria de entender porque este erro acontece:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>     at logName (<anonymous>:1:24)
>     at <anonymous>:5:1
> ```

Código:

```js
function logName({ name = 'Anonymous' }) {
  console.log(name);
}

logName();
```

Se eu estou fornecendo um valor padrão para `name`, penso que o JavaScript deveria entender que se trata de um argumento opcional e não lançar erro.

No entanto, parece que não é bem isso que acontece. Por quê?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É sabido que desestruturação nada mais é que açúcar sintático para operações comuns que envolvem acesso em objetos (o que inclui o indexamento de arrays).

Portanto, o código:

```
function logName({ name = 'Anonymous' }) {
  console.log(name);
}
```

É *equivalente* a algo como:

```
1 | function logName(_ref) {
2 |   const _ref$name = _ref.name;
3 |   const name = _ref$name === undefined ? 'Anonymous' : _ref$name;
4 |
5 |   console.log(name);
6 | }
```

<sup>Adaptado do [Babel Playground](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGzgcwHIEMC2BTACgG9Exc9EBeRAcgEEwEBPHOEAZxsQF8BKRIgChEiCAnZxkeAHSo0BMvl4BuQdyA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=true&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.12.13&externalPlugins=).</sup>

Se prestar atenção na linha 2, verá que ocorre um acesso de propriedade ao objeto passado como argumento. No caso, ocorre `_ref.name`.

A partir daí, podemos chegar em duas conclusões:

- O valor padrão na desestruturação refere-se à **propriedade**, e não ao **argumento** (possivelmente opcional) da função.
- Se o argumento não for fornecido, `_ref` (o primeiro parâmetro) será `undefined`. E, de praxe do JavaScript, `undefined.name` (ou qualquer outro acesso de propriedade em `undefined` ou `null`) lança um `TypeError`.

Desse modo, se houver a possibilidade do argumento ser opcional, é preciso fornecer um valor padrão para o parâmetro também. Algo como:

```
//                                      ↓↓↓↓
function logName({ name = 'Anonymous' } = {}) {
  console.log(name);
}
```

No exemplo acima, definimos um novo objeto literal "vazio" como valor padrão para o **primeiro parâmetro** da função `logName`. É importante entender a diferença:

- A string `'Anonymous'` é um valor padrão para uma **propriedade** do objeto.
- O literal "vazio" `{}` é um valor padrão para o **primeiro argumento** da função.

São bem diferentes, porque nada adianta definir valor padrão para uma propriedade de um objeto que nem sequer existe. Apenas como último questionamento para sistematizar: como o JavaScript poderia avaliar se a propriedade existe ou não (para depois atribuir um possível valor de propriedade padrão) se o parâmetro é `undefined`?

---

Apenas como curiosidade, quando valor padrão para a propriedade é fornecido na desestruturação, a mensagem de erro é algo como:

> ```
> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
> ```

Mas quando não se fornece valor de propriedade padrão, a mensagem é um pouco mais compreensível:

> ```
> Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
> ```

Veja:

```js
try {
  // Sem valor padrão:
  // Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
  const { name } = undefined;
} catch ({ message }) {
  console.log(message);
}

try {
  // Com valor padrão:
  // Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
  const { name = 'Default' } = undefined;
} catch ({ message }) {
  console.log(message);
}
```